# Get size of 3D char* Array

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm trying to make a multidimensional array, which holds weapons and their attachments:
I have lots of arrays like this:

```
char *G18[19] = { "glock_mp", "glock_akimbo_mp", "glock_eotech_mp", "glock_fmj_mp", "glock_reflex_mp", "glock_silencer_mp", "glock_xmags_mp", "glock_akimbo_fmj_mp", "glock_akimbo_silencer_mp", "glock_akimbo_xmags_mp", "glock_eotech_fmj_mp",
        "glock_eotech_silencer_mp", "glock_eotech_xmags_mp", "glock_fmj_reflex_mp", "glock_fmj_silencer_mp", "glock_fmj_xmags_mp", "glock_reflex_silencer_mp", "glock_reflex_xmags_mp", "glock_silencer_xmags_mp" };
```

But all weapons don't belong to same category, f.e. an AK47 is an Assault Rifle and this G18 is a Machine Gun. So i created 2D Arrays which represnt a category, like so:

```
char **MACHINEGUNS[4] = { G18, TMP, RAFFICA, PP2000 };
```

so now i have the weapons sorted i created another array which should hold the categories, like so:

```
char ***WEAPONS[7] = { ASSAULTRIFLES, SUBMACHINEGUNS, LIGHTMACHINEGUNS, SNIPERS, PISTOLS, MACHINEGUNS, SHOTGUNS };
```

accessing the weapons like

```
char *weapon = WEAPONS[assaultrifle][ak47][0]; // assaultrifle & ak47 are enum mebers
```

works perfectly fine. The problem i'm facing is that i can't get the row and column sizes. F.e. if i want to know how many weapon classes their are i would do:

```
sizeof(WEAPONS)
```

which gives me 7. If i want to know how many assaultrifles there are i do:

```
sizeof(WEAPONS[assaultrifles])
```

But here's the problem: This gives me 4 although the assaultrifle's array size is 9:

```
char **ASSAULTRIFLES[9] = { AK47, M16A4, M4A1, FN2000, ACR, FAMAS, FAL, SCARH, TAR21 };
```

it returns 4 aswell if i do this:

```
sizeof(WEAPONS[assaultrifles][ak47])
```

even though the ak47's array size is 39. Any idea why it's not working and how i could achiev this? Thanks in advance and sorry for the long text!

Comment: Please don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).  Use things like `std::string`, `std::vector` and objects and references in their place.

Comment: @NathanOliver i can only use char (don't ask it's just like that, because the project is for a game and all the games inputs are in char * and .c_str() mixes up the ingame strings at some point). Also idk how to use vectors yet, so if you could give me an example that would be great :)

Comment: You 're getting always 4 because you 're actually getting the pointer size in bytes.

Comment: @DimChtz how would i get the actuall size!? and thanks for your reply!

Comment: @SupaDupa I still don't see why you are using multiple char *'s even if it is for a game, several games use the std::string in their code, even for user input.  As for the actual size, you will need to store and track that information manually.

Comment: Also you should look up enum's and vectors, you could also look into maps.

Comment: " i can only use char (don't ask it's just like that, because the project is for a game and all the games inputs are in char *" Well that doesn't mean you can't use `std::vector` or `std::string`, etc. Just saying ...

Comment: @DimChtz i can use vectors, but i only now the basics and not how to do a 3d array with them and i cant use std::string as i said, i've already tried and it just doesnt work and i dont like convertig between char* and std::string all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "getting the size" of an array at runtime in C or C++. You can get the size of an array (declared with `[<size>]`) with `sizeof` because its size is known at compile time. When you get the `sizeof` a pointer you are literally getting how many bytes a pointer takes, which is why you get 4. If you want to know the size of a vector at runtime, the typical options are:

- Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and [STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) in general. There are a million tutorials and examples out there that you can check about that.
- Instead of storing raw arrays (or pointers to arrays), store simple `struct`s or `class`es containing the pointer to the array and the size. This is kinda like rolling your own, limited `std::vector`, and you have to be careful of freeing the memory correctly where necessary and so on, so I'm not sure it's a great choice.
- Some other dirty C-like trick like adding `NULL`/`nullptr` at the end of every array and then iterate through the whole thing until you reach it every time you need to find the size. Inefficient and error-prone.

So, yeah, in short, use `std::vector` or other containers.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm currently loking into how to use std::vector :)